# Wallaby with Browserify and TypeScript modules

Tags: testing, typescript, browserify, wallaby.js

I am trying to get Wallaby to work with a TypeScript app, using Browserify and Wallabify. However, when I run Wallaby, it outputs **`No failing tests, 0 passing`**, and all test indicators are grey.

The file `app/spec.setup.ts` is responsible for loading node modules dependencies such as chai, sinon, and the app's main module. `app/spec.util.ts` provides some helpers, imported by individual spec files.

```
module.exports = function() {
  var wallabify = require('wallabify');

  var wallabyPostprocessor = wallabify({
        entryPatterns: [
          'app/spec.setup.ts',
          'app/src/**/*.spec.ts'
        ]
      }
  );

  return {
    files: [
      {pattern: 'app/spec.setup.ts', load: false, instrument: false},
      {pattern: 'app/spec.util.ts', load: false, instrument: false},
      {pattern: 'app/src/**/*.ts', load: false},
      {pattern: 'app/src/**/*.spec.ts', ignore: true}
    ],

    tests: [
      {pattern: 'app/src/**/*.spec.ts', load: false}
    ],

    testFramework: 'mocha',

    postprocessor: wallabyPostprocessor,

    bootstrap: function (w) {
      // outputs test file names, with .ts extensions changed to .js
      console.log(w.tests);

      window.__moduleBundler.loadTests();
    }
  };
};
```

What's interesting is that I don't get any feedback from changing `entryPatterns`, even setting it to an empty array or invalid file names. The result is still the same. Only if I remove it *entirely*, I get errors such as `Can't find variable: sinon`.

I've also figured that the `entryPatterns` list may need the compiled file names, i.e. `.js` instead of `.ts` extension. However, when I do that, I get `Postprocessor run failure: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'` on `spec.setup.ts`.

I don't know what is the correct way to configure Wallabify for TypeScript compilation, and I couldn't find any complete examples on the web, so I'd appreciate any hints.

*P.S. with my current StackOverflow reputation I couldn't add two new tags: `wallaby` and `wallabify`. Could someone do me a favour and add the two tags please.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [TypeScript compiler renames files to `.js` and applied before wallabify](https://github.com/wallabyjs/wallabify/issues/5#issuecomment-151002859), you need to change your entry patterns like this to make it work:

```
entryPatterns: [
      'app/spec.setup.js',
      'app/src/**/*.spec.js'
    ]
```

Comment: what is wallabify?

Comment: Wallabify (https://github.com/wallabyjs/wallabify) is an OSS postprocessor for wallaby to support Browserify: https://wallabyjs.com/docs/integration/browserify.html.